# Where can I safely store passwords in Swift? Is CloudKit alright?

Tags: security, swift, user-accounts, cloudkit

I am creating an app that uses accounts. What would be the best way to store the data(i.e. username, password, etc...)? I have already implemented CloudKit, so could I somehow store it there?

If I were to use Keychain Access, how would I then store information in the cloud based off of that account?

Comment: why do you need authentication at all, one way is iCloud authentication in Apple ecosystem, or there is FaceBook authentication, with Facebook Login Button

Answer (score 1):

To more safely store passwords you should store these in the keychain. Depending upon the settings the keychain is shared among differing iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

you should never store passwords unencrypted anywhere. When you do want to store passwords, then use a one way hash. that way you could see if a supplied password is valid by comparing the hashes, but there is no way to get hold of the original password.

I understand from your question that you want to store them on a central location? Then CloudKit could be an option. But if you only need it on the device itself, then store it in the keychain.

Comment: The problem with CloudKit is that the data is public(I am not about to store it on people's own iCloud's). Would something like Parse our Azure be better for this?

Comment: Yes, it's a public DB, but it can only be read using your app. So they can't go outside it's possibilities. Besides that you could also set the security that it can only be read by the creator. Where are you going to need the password for? If you only need it on the device itself, then also only store it on the device (keychain)